# Being a SO moderator counts as moderator on 2 SE sites on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51

On Area 51 commitment phase users list ([example](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338?phase=commitment&committers=userreputation#tab-top)), the usercard shows on how many sites you are a moderator. But if you are a Stack Overflow moderator, the usercard shows that you are a moderator on 2 Stack Exchange sites:

[image: Area 51 Usercards]

As you can see, the usercard shows that they are a moderator on two sites, but when you look at their network profile, you can see that they are only a moderator on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The diamond count on Area 51 is cumulative, that is, even if you are no longer a moderator on the site, the count still reflects that participation.

Back before the MSO/MSE split, all of the Stack Overflow moderators were moderators on the then Meta Stack Overflow.  This is no longer the case with Meta Stack Exchange, where only the [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do) (and of course staff/developers who already have diamonds across the network, thanks Shadow Wizard) have moderator powers for the time being.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thanks!

Comment: Last sentence is not true. Developers also have moderator powers, and any SE employee who might need a diamond. (including support team e.g. of Careers)

Comment: @ShadowWizard You are correct.  I simplified my addition to that sentence so that it didn't turn into a laundry list ;)  Feel free to adjust if you think it's not clear.

Comment: Better now, cheers! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Much appreciated, as always!