# Diamonds are still preserved in the Top Beta Users section of old closed proposals

Tags: bug, area-51, moderators

I noticed something weird when looking in [this old, closed, proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614?phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top) on Area 51:

> [image]

You see it too? Right, none of these users have diamonds by now, even Jeff. Can they also be removed from that list? (The diamonds, not the users.)

Comment: Looks like user's full status (name, rep, badges) is fixed on the close date. So I'm not sure that this is a bug at all.

Comment: @alexolut true and I don't mind for the name, rep, etc (e.g. name is also fixed on all sites in delete/close messages for deleted users) but diamond is another story and much more confusing.

Comment: I think, diamonds for closed sites mean nothing for now.

Comment: But it can be usefull for history.

Comment: @alexolut diamond on Area 51 means "this user is moderator somewhere in Stack Exchange", it does not mean moderator on the specific site of the proposal. (there can also be several diamonds)

Comment: "several diamonds"? Where I can see this?

Comment: @alexolut oops, checked again, meant there is number next to the diamond in several views, e.g. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235115/being-a-so-moderator-counts-as-moderator-on-2-se-sites-on-area-51).

Comment: Seems I found an answer for your current question on the post what link you just provided: *"even if you are no longer a moderator on the site, the count still reflects that participation"*. I.e. [tag:status-bydesign]